# Is expiring and gc pruning sufficient to clean up a git repository?

Tags: git, security

I have a git repository that originally had commits adding "secret" data in ancillary files.  I have completely rebased the entire history minus the commits adding the files, followed by `git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive` as one is instructed to do after using the `bfg` tool.  Assume this repository does not have any remotes (I'll be creating a new one to track the new history and deleting the old).  Is my repository now "clean", or should I still be concerned about any data still lingering in git limbo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're safe now, but if your secrets were ever on a remote, you should still rotate them as soon as is convenient.